# Why does the append method return None with my list?

Tags: python, list, append

I know I can use "append()" to add an element to a list, but why does the assignment return None?

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> a.append(4)
>>> print a 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a=a.append(5)
>>> print a 
None
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

Because you're assigning an output to the act of appending which has no output, so instead of:

```
a=a.append(5)
```

you just want

```
a.append(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

I try to explain in the easiest way:
With:

```
a.append(5)
```

you are calling the function that adds something (in this case *5*) to a

With:

```
a = a.append(5)
```

you are saying that *a* is equal the result of the funcion *.append()*. But 
*append* just modifies an existing list, it does not returns anything, and it does not, as you thought, return a new list with the element appended.

Comment: This is factually incorrect. If the append returned "the function of adding something to a list", then you would be able to call the result as a function. It is not doing that; it's simply returning nothing.

Comment: Saying a = function() (where function() returns 1) is the same as a = 1. So if .append() returns *None*, a = append(5) will return *None* as well. However I tried to explain it better

Comment: That's true, but your statement "`a` is equal to the function of adding something to the list" is still misleading because `a` will not equal any kind of function. This is a distinction that is very important because variables _can_ equal functions in Python, and it is very common to have functions return functions (decorators, for example).

Comment: Yeah, you're right, what I wanted to say is "*a* is equal to the result of the funcion of adding something to the list"

Comment: I think your latest edit helps a lot and makes it clear what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

This just indicates that the "append" method does not return anything. It only modifies the existing list. It does not return an updated list.

Don't bother doing `a = a.append(4)`. If you just want to add an entry to the list, do `a.append(4)` to modify `a`.